# Como executar o Dockerfile dentro do Docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker

Essa é uma esqueleto genérico de um arquivo docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
   db:
      image: mongo:3.4
  backend:
      image: node:8.1
      volumes:
        -./backend:/backend
      ports:
      - 3000:3000
      command: bash -c "cd /backend && npm i && node app"
  frontend:
      image: nginx:1.13
      volumes:
        - ./frontend:/usr/shared/nginx/html
      ports:
        - 80:80
```

Supondo que o arquivo Dockerfile esteja na mesma raiz do arquivo docker-compose.yml como eu poderia executar o Dockerfile através do arquivo docker-compose.yml ?

Estou aberto a perguntas

Comment: Ao invés de "image" coloque "build: ."

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss muito obrigado por me ajudar, teria como colocar a sua sugestão? Porque você explicando assim eu não consigo ter ideia, por favor!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na versão 3 do Docker Compose existe a opção `build` para informar um Dockerfile local para montar a imagem do container.

```
version: "3"
services:
    myapp:
        build: .
```

Isso montará a imagem do conatainer `myapp` a partir do arquivo Dockerfile no mesmo diretório, pois o `.` indica o caminho deste arquivo. Se estiver em outro diretório você pode fazer algo como:

```
version: "3"
services:
    myapp:
        build: ./myapp/
```

Caso não queira que seja o arquivo Dockerfile o utilizado, mas sim um arquivo com outro nome, você pode especificar o nome com `dockerfile`:

```
version: "3"
services:
    myapp:
        build: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-test
```

E, se junto a isso você utilizar a opção `image`, será montada a imagem utilizando o nome e tag informadas nessa opção.

```
version: "3"
services:
    myapp:
        build: .
        image: myapp:1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Complementando a resposta de @Woss, na versão 3.9 do docker-compose, a sintase para indicar uma Dockerfile específica para o build é a seguinte:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    myapp:
        build:
            context: . #indica o dir da Dockerfile
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-test
```

É necessário passar tanto o `context` (caminho relativo p/ a dockerfile) quanto o nome da dockerfile indentados dentro de `build`.